# php foreach only echoes second value

Tags: php, loops, foreach

trying to show images depending on what the value is in a foreach loop and it echoes right the second time but not the first one..weird this is that if I echo the value it does show it but not the image thats in a switch statement..here's the code:

```
foreach ($myarray as $value ){
    echo $value;
    switch($value){
        case 'value1':
            echo '<img src="something.jpg" />';
            break;
        case 'value2':
            echo '<img src="something-2.jpg" />';
            break;
    }
}
```

so if one has both "value1" and "value2" then it echoes both values, but only echoes the value2 image..help?

Comment: You'll need to post more code - what you've given us works fine: https://eval.in/113932

Comment: thanks, found out the error was that "value1" inside the array had a space afterwards..found it by doing a var_dump.. values is from wordpress. thanks anyways.. also not sure if it was you but kinda quick on requesting the question to be "closed" when it is a valid question..I always post as much code as I thought necessary

Comment: For future, proper debugging techniques would've solved this for you before you reached StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are only seeing the second value because it is overwriting the first.
In theory, you should only have a 1:1 match for your case.

Make sure your value types are correct. Meaning "1" (string) and 1 (number) could be interrupted differently.

Also, if you will have a time where you could have two results, you can always double up the case.

```
switch ($value) {
    case 'FOO':
        case 'FOOBAR':
        echo '<img >';
    break;
    case 'BAR':
        echo '<img>';
    break;
    default:
      // No match found. 
    break;
}
```

However, it wouldn't make much sense to have 1 and 2 be in the same case. Otherwise, what's the point of the switch - all values are going to give the same result.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, the issue was that my 'FOO' had an extra space so it wasn't being catched.